# Delete certain parts of html code on the iPhone after downloading it

Tags: iphone, html

I'm wondering if it's possible to edit out certain parts of the html code. It's really longa and as I parse it (with element parser), the deeper the parser goes into the code the slower it runs. Any ideas? I'm using a 3G as well.

edit:
For example on this site I'd want the posts and the usernames. Let's say there are like 50 replies on this thread and assume it will take a long time for the 3G phone to parse thousands of lines.

I'd want to remove the right links, the ads, the links at the top and bottom of the page too. Then I'd get the revised html and push it into the parser.

Comment: How is the html downloaded? What kind of edits do you intend to do?

Comment: If you want a useful answer, you need to be more specific about how you are parsing the HTML and what you plan to do with it. Right now your question is vague.

Comment: ah ok. Well I'm getting the html by using stringWithContentsOFURL then parsing it with element parser.
What I plan to do with the html before it gets parsed is remove any html code that I don't need.

For example on this site I'd want the posts and the usernames. Let's say there are like 50 replies on this thread and assume it will take a long time for the 3G phone to parse thousands of lines.

I'd want to remove the right links, the ads, the links at the top and bottom of the page too. Then I'd get the revised html and push it into the parser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you downloading a webpage using UIWebView, then you can use normal javascript to (by using the method `stringByEvaluatingJavascriptFromString`) to hide or remove any elements you want to remove from the view of the user.